# Is there a way of creating an instance of a type with test data?

Tags: c#, autofixture, nbuilder

I have a type and want to create an instance of it with test data.

I know that frameworks like **NBuilder** or **AutoFixture** can create instances of types that are known on design time (`<T>`). Are those frameworks able to create an instance based on a type that is only known at runtime (`Type`)?

On the end I want to do something like:

```
var value = Builder.Create(type);
var constant = Expression.Constant(value, type);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AutoFixture does indeed support this. But, as far as I know, there are no convenience extension methods to do this.

The following generic code:

```
var value = fixture.CreateAnonymous<MyType>();
```

would look like this with a type only known at runtime:

```
var context = new SpecimenContext(fixture.Compose());
var value = context.Resolve(new SeededRequest(typeof(MyType), null))
```

Comment: That works :) Is it possible to register an implementation of an interface for AutoFixture when AutoFixture tries to create an instance for a property where the type is an interface?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Please ask it as a seperate question. I will answer it there.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949417/register-an-implementation-of-an-interface-for-autofixture

Comment: There is no `fixture.Compose()` method in my version of AutoFixture