# AutoFixture: mock methods don't return a frozen instance

Tags: moq, autofixture

I'm trying to write this simple test:

```csharp
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

var postProcessingAction = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IPostProcessingAction>>();
var postProcessor = fixture.Freeze<PostProcessor>();

postProcessor.Process("", "");

postProcessingAction.Verify(action => action.Do());
```

The `Verify` check fails.
The code for postProcessor.Process is

```csharp
public void Process(string resultFilePath, string jobId)
{
    IPostProcessingAction postProcessingAction =
        postProcessingActionReader
            .CreatePostProcessingActionFromJobResultXml(resultFilePath);

    postProcessingAction.Do();
}
```

`postProcessingActionReader` is an interface field initialized through the constructor.

I'm expecting the test to pass but it fails, it turns out the instance of `IPostProessingAction` returned from the `CreatePostProcessingActionFromJobResultXml` method is not the same instance as returned from `fixture.Freeze<>`.

My expectation was that after freezing this Mock object it would inject the underlying mock of the `IPostProcessingAction` interface in every place its required as well as make all mock methods returning `IPostProcessingAction` return this same object.

Is my expectation about the return value of the mock methods incorrect?
Is there a way to change this behavior so that mock methods return the same frozen instance?

Comment: How does the `postProcessingActionReader` implementation looks like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `Freeze` the `IPostProcessingActionReader` component.

The following test will pass:

```csharp
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture()
        .Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

    var postProcessingActionMock = new Mock<IPostProcessingAction>();

    var postProcessingActionReaderMock = fixture
        .Freeze<Mock<IPostProcessingActionReader>>();

    postProcessingActionReaderMock
        .Setup(x => x.CreatePostProcessingActionFromJobResultXml(
            It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(postProcessingActionMock.Object);

    var postProcessor = fixture.CreateAnonymous<PostProcessor>();
    postProcessor.Process("", "");

    postProcessingActionMock.Verify(action => action.Do());
}
```

Assuming that the types are defined as:

```csharp
public interface IPostProcessingAction
{
    void Do();
}

public class PostProcessor
{
    private readonly IPostProcessingActionReader actionReader;

    public PostProcessor(IPostProcessingActionReader actionReader)
    {
        if (actionReader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("actionReader");

        this.actionReader = actionReader;
    }

    public void Process(string resultFilePath, string jobId)
    {
        IPostProcessingAction postProcessingAction = this.actionReader
            .CreatePostProcessingActionFromJobResultXml(resultFilePath);

        postProcessingAction.Do();
    }
}

public interface IPostProcessingActionReader
{
    IPostProcessingAction CreatePostProcessingActionFromJobResultXml(
        string resultFilePath);
}
```

---

In case you use AutoFixture [declaratively](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/08/AutoDataTheoriesWithAutoFixture.aspx) with the xUnit.net [extension](http://nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.Xunit/) the test could be simplified even further:

```csharp
[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void Test(
    [Frozen]Mock<IPostProcessingActionReader> readerMock,
    Mock<IPostProcessingAction> postProcessingActionMock,
    PostProcessor postProcessor)
{
    readerMock
        .Setup(x => x.CreatePostProcessingActionFromJobResultXml(
            It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(postProcessingActionMock.Object);

    postProcessor.Process("", "");

    postProcessingActionMock.Verify(action => action.Do());
}
```

The `AutoMoqDataAttribute` is defined as:

```csharp
internal class AutoMoqDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    internal AutoMoqDataAttribute()
        : base(new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization()))
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer! I wonder if there's a library like AutoFixture which would go further and set up method return results on mocks automatically so I don't have to do the extra work of return value setup.

Comment: You are welcome! Currently, you can try to automatically fill the properties of auto-mocked instances with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12958274/467754).

Answer (score 5):

As of 3.20.0, you can use `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization`. This will automatically configure all mocks so that their members' return values are generated by AutoFixture.

In other words, it will auto-configure your `postProcessingActionReader` to return the frozen `postProcessingAction`.

Just change this:

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
```

to this:

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization());
```