# Why AutoMoqCustomization nested dependencies don't respect frozen mocks?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, autofixture

I've tried using the `AutoMoqCustomization` in order to auto-mock an object graph with nested dependencies and results are not as I expected. Below is the failing test code (assertions using FluentAssertions). When running the test, the `IDependant` injected to `Dependant2` has a different `IObject` mock than the one frozen earlier. Is this a bug in mocks freezing, or am I not understanding correctly how to use it?

Note: I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709025/autofixture-mock-methods-dont-return-a-frozen-instance) regarding using `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization` and it doesn't work when `IDependant` has a property `IObject Obj { get; }` but does work when it has a method `IObject GetObj();`, is this the expected behavior of `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization`?

The failing test code:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{
     [TestMethod]
     public void Test()
     {
         var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

         var objMock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IObject>>();
         var sut = fixture.Create<Dependant2>();

         sut.Obj.Should().BeSameAs(objMock);
     }
}

public interface IObject { }

public interface IDependant { IObject Obj { get; } }

public class MyObject : IObject { }

public class Dependant2
{
    public Dependant2(IDependant dependant)
    {
       Obj = dependant.Obj; 
    }

    public IObject Obj { get; }
}
```

Comment: This question was also asked and resolved in [the AutoFixture GitHub repository](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/608).

Comment: it was *closed*, but I would not call it resolved.  It's due to a bug in Moq that hasn't been fixed, and the only workaround I've been able to find is to use an older version of Moq