# Autofixture couldnt work with interfaces properties?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, autofixture

I have a class `Alias`. I have used it with Autofixture and everything have been working OK. The tests started to fail however when I've added an interface property to my class.

So that's my class:

```
public class Alias : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Alias()
    {
        Nicks = new List<string>();
        History = new History(this);
    }
    
    public IDownloader Downloader {get;set;}
}
```

I am using it in test like that:

```
Fixture fixture =  new Fixture();

var alias = fixture.Create<Alias>();
```

And got Exception:

> loeh.AutoFixture.ObjectCreationException : AutoFixture was unable to create an instance from Core.Helpers.IDownloader...

I've tried to register the interface by `fixture.Register<IVKDownloader>(() => new Downloader());` but I still get this error.

If I change this property to use type instead of the interface `public Downloader Downloader {get;set;}` everything is working normally. How could I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to let Autofixture create an instance of a type that contains properties with an interface type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949417/how-to-let-autofixture-create-an-instance-of-a-type-that-contains-properties-wit)

Comment: Why do you expect `fixture.Register<IVKDownloader>` to impact how `IDownloader` is being created?

Comment: Is that a typo of `IVKDownloader` instead of `IDownloder`? If not that might be why it isn't working

Comment: @Seekeer ok I'll add it as an answer then, glad its working! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fixture.Register<IVKDownloader>(() => new Downloader());` Looks like that is a typo for `IDownloader`

`fixture.Register<IDownloader>(() => new Downloader());`